# Adding to a map with mutable values

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose I have a `map<string, vector<int>>` called `my_map` and I want to associate `42` to the key `"foo"`. Coming from Java I would expect to have to do something like this

```
if (my_map.find("foo") != my_map.end()) {
    my_map["foo"].push_back(42);
} else {
    vector<int> my_vector;
    my_map["foo"] = my_vector;
    my_vector.push_back(42);
}
```

To my surprise I found that I can just do

```
my_map["foo"].push_back(42);
```

How does this work? What would `my_map["foo"]` do if the type of the map's values did not have a constructor with no parameters? Suppose you wanted to initialise all values in a manner other than using an empty constructor? In Java, I could do

```
map.computeIfAbsent("foo", **some supplier of Vectors**).add(42);
```

Is there an equivalent in C++?

Comment: `vector<int> my_vector; my_map["foo"] = my_vector; my_vector.push_back(42);` In your `else`, what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Containers store copies. C++ is not java, not everything is a reference....

Comment: I think that what happens is the fact that when you try to insert an element if "foo" is not found a new map cell is created. during the creation the default constructor for the vector is called creating already for you an empty vector

Comment: @FirstStep I'm trying to understand what is going on. What does `my_map["foo"]` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`my_map["foo"]` default-constructs a new value if it doesn't already exist. Thus, it would cause a compilation error if the value type was not default-constructible (i.e. didn't have a constructor with no parameter). You would then have to do the following :

```
my_map.emplace("foo", param).first->second.push_back(42);
```

Where [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) would construct your value from `param` if it didn't already exist.

More parameters can be supplied with the piecewise constructor from `std::pair` :

```
my_map.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple("foo"),
    std::forward_as_tuple(param1, param2, param3)
).first->second.push_back(42);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/) for `operator[]` :

> If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).

If the `mapped_type` doesn't have a default constructor, you'd get a compilation error.